# Filter Array of objects and count the filtered elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I  have   array  of  different  objects    which  look like  this:

```
[{
   color:'red',
   'type':'2',
   'status':'true'
 }
 {
   color:'red',
   'type':'2',
   'status':'false'
 }]
```

I want  to  filter the one element like  `status`  and then  count  the  filtered, for example if  status is false  then return 1.

I have tried  the  below  code  but I am not  sure  what I am  doing  here:

```
for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
  var check2;

  console.log(check[i].isApproved);
  (function(check2) {
    return check2 = check.filter(function(val) { 
        return val == false 
    }).length;
  })(check2)

  console.log('again Rides',check2);
}
```

Comment: Further explanation is required. The word 'filtered' is being used too liberally. This is very unclear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could just do a count, or you could run a filter and get the length of the final array.

```
var count = 0;
var arr = [{color:'red', type:'2', status:'true'},
           {color:'red', type:'2', status:'false'} ];
// Showing filterin to be robust. You could just do this in 
// a loop, which would be sensible if you didn't need the subarray. 
var filtered = arr.filter ( function ( d ) {
    // Note that I'm testing for a string, not a boolean, because
    // you are using strings as values in your objects. 
    // If it was a boolean, you'd use if ( d.status ) { ... }
    count++;
    return d.status === 'false';
});

// These should be the same, reflecting number of objs with 'false'
console.log ( count );
console.log ( filtered.length );
// This should trace out a sub array of objs with status === 'false'
console.log ( filtered );
```

Answer (score 26):

If I understood correctly you want to count the number of elements where `status` is equal to `'false'` **note**: The values you have in `status` are strings

```js
var check = [
  { color:'red', 'type':'2', 'status':'true' }, 
  { color:'red', 'type':'2', 'status':'false' } 
];

var countfiltered = check.filter(function(element){
    return element.status == 'false';
}).length

console.log(countfiltered);
```

Comment: Updated with newer JS features: `const countfiltered = check.filter((c) => c.status === "false").length;`

Answer (score 10):

Given this dataset:

```js
const items = [
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'true' }, 
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'false' } 
];
```

Here are two way to solve the problem:

### Using reduce

```js
const falseNb = items.reduce((n, item) => item.status === 'false' ? n+1 : n, 0)
```

### Using filter

```js
const falseNb = items.filter(e => e.status === 'false').length;
```

Please note that according to [this test](https://perf.link/#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%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%2BIGUuc3RhdHVzID09PSAnZmFsc2UnKS5sZW5ndGgiLCJydW5zIjpbMzAwMCwxMDAwLDMwMDAsMjAwMCwyMDAwLDMwMDAsNjcwMDAsMjAwMCw3MjAwMCwxMDAwMCwzOTQwMDAsNzIwMDAsMjAwMCwyOTAwMCwxMDAwMCwyMTUwMDAsMTAwMDAsMTY3MDAwLDIwMDAsMjMzMDAwLDIwMDAsMjAwMDAsMzAwMCwxMDAwLDIwMDAsMzAwMCwxODcwMDAsMjAwMCwyMDAwLDMwMDAsMjAwMCw3MjAwMCwxMDAwLDMwMDAsMTEwMDAsMzAwMCwyMDAwLDk4MDAwLDkwMDAsMjAwMDAsMTAwMDAsMTgwMDAsMjAwMCw5ODAwMCwzMDAwLDExMDAwLDEzMDAwLDIwMDAsMjAwMCw0OTkwMDAsMTAwMDAsNjAwMCwyMDAwLDMwMDAsODQwMDAsMzAwMCwzMDAwLDEwMDAsMTAwMDAsMjAwMDAsMTAwMCwxMDAwLDk4MDAwLDEwMDAwLDIwMDAwLDIwMDAsMTAxMDAwLDEwMDAwMCwyMDAwLDEwMDAsOTAwMCwzMDAwLDIwMDAsMzAwMCwxMTAwMCw5MjAwMCwxMTAwMCwzMDAwLDIwMDAwLDExMDAwLDQwNjAwMCwyMDAwLDcyMDAwLDExMDAwLDExMDAwLDIxMjAwMCw2MDAwLDIwMDAsNzIwMDAsMzAwMCwzMDAwLDIxNTAwMCwxMDAwMCwyMDAwLDIwMDAsMjAwMCwzMDAwLDEwMDAwLDIwMDAsMjAwMF0sIm9wcyI6NDA5NDB9XSwidXBkYXRlZCI6IjIwMjMtMDEtMDZUMTU6MDU6NTcuNjY0WiJ9), the **reduce method is twice more performant**

```js
const items = [
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'true' }, 
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'green', type:'1', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'red', type:'1', status:'true' } 
]

const falseNb = items.reduce((n, e) => e.status === 'false' ? n+1 : n, 0)

document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = falseNb

const falseNbFilter = items.filter(e => e.status === 'false').length

document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = falseNb
```

```css
body { background: #333; color: #0f0; font-family: monospace}
```

```html
<pre>
[
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'true' }, 
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'red', type:'2', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'green', type:'1', status:'false' } ,
  { color:'red', type:'1', status:'true' } 
]
</pre>
Result with Reduce => <span id='result1'></span><br><br>

Result with Filter => <span id='result2'></span>
```